# Lettuce django integration

Tags: python, django, lettuce, splinter

I have an issue with Lettuce + Django + Splinter. Lettuce does not seem to be able to pick up changes to the database. Below, `create_user` and `create_post` generate and save a user and a few post models. However when splinter opens the browser - there seem to be no posts on the page, when I try to access the list view.

I am running lettuce via `python manage.py harvest --test-server`.

```
@step(ur'visit "(.*)" url')
def visit_url(step, name):
    [create_post().save() for i in xrange(2)]
    world.browser = Browser()
    world.browser.visit(django_url(url))
```

The URL I am trying to access is a Post list view, and same construction works perfectly from django's test framework, so I know it is not an issue with django or splinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set a `LETTUCE_TEST_SERVER` value to a test runner based on Django `LiveServerTestCase`. Thus, I had to add a line to `settings.py`:

```
LETTUCE_TEST_SERVER = 'lettuce.django.server.DjangoServer'
```

This seem to be an undocumented feature from a following pull request: https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/pull/395.